# Should cpu-intensive operations be processed client side if possible?

Tags: json, node.js

I am currently serving a page on my website that renders statistical data formed from thousands of data points. None of the data is sensitive, so security is not a concern.

My first instinct would be to send all the data to be processed by the client so that it doesn't slow doesn't slow the server; yet, I am not sure if it is considered bad practice, or if it is even potentially slower to send large amounts of data instead of rendering it into just a few numbers first.

The data is all stored as JSON if it matters

Comment: if you're satisfied please close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The specifics matter here. Can you send 512KB of data to the browser for successful processing? On desktops, almost certainly yes. Can you send 20MB? No. Try it and see how it works. If you code in a clean style, running in node vs the browser should be something you can easily experiment trying both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would refrain from punishing the users of your site, and run CPU intensive operations on the server side where possible.

Are users of your site going to eventually use a mobile device to visit?  Do you want them waiting for your data to load/process?

It's hard to know for sure, but I'd err on the server side for all but the things client's truly need.